# Adding standard Java libraries with SBT

Tags: scala

How does one add standard Java libraries to SBT. For example, my class relies on these imports:

```
import javax.mail._
import javax.mail.internet._
import java.util.Properties
```

Trying to compile with SBT fails if I use these, for example:

```
[error] /Users/jacobus/scalaprojects/doxy/src/main/scala/EmailService.scala:6: expected class or object definition
[error]   val props = new Properties();
```

Here's the source:

```
import java.util.Properties
import javax.mail._
import javax.mail.internet._

val props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
val session = Session.getInstance(props);
val message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@testtesttest123.com"));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "test@testtesttest123.com");
message.setSubject("This is the Subject");
message.setText("This is the Message");
val transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect("localhost","username","password")
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be relative to the import but rather to the lack of a class / object definition in your class. Might it be the case?

Comment: I wish it was, but the code runs fine in Idea. I just can't compile it with SBT

Comment: I've had this problem before where the Twitter Finagle libraries also depended on javax and could also not include it.

Comment: You get that error because you try to compile a scala script file as if it's a scala source file. In a scala source file all val statements must be inside a scala object or a scala class. A scala script file can be run with scala, but can't be compiled with scalac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not compilable code: it's a script. A script can be run, but cannot be compiled.

Put that stuff inside a standard application declaration, like `object MyApp extends App {`, and you might get *other* errors, but not this one.

Comment: Thanks D. I was having a blonde moment. That gets me the dufus award for the day.